# Confusing wording: “Your event cannot be less than 72 hours away” Event within 3 days: false. What does the false imply?

Tags: grammar, american-english

I requested an exchange for tickets for a concert. The exchange was requested the 16th around 11:30PM. The concert is on the 19th at 9pm. The fine print read the exchange will be invalid if “the event is less than 72 hours away.” At the end of the email it read, “Event within 3 days: false.” Does the false mean we’re not breaking the rule and we can exchange the tickets? Technically the event is less than 72 hours away from the exchange request time, yet the date is technically still the 16th. Or did we just waste money and accidentally bought more tickets? As the exchange will not go through if we messed up.

Comment: Check the website policies/ask them. 72 hours means 72 hours, but 3 days is vaguer.

Comment: 'You may not exchange tickets if you make a request to do so less than 72 hours from the start time of the event.' Yes, the email mangles the explanation for refusal, but the 'fine print' is precise and unarguable.

Answer (score 1):

"Event within 3 days: false" looks to me like the automated output of a validation condition, which if true would have meant that you're too close to the time of the event to make an exchange.

This sounds like a very confusing design decision, and you should contact the company for clarification.

Comment: The small print is probably checked more carefully than the software (based on my experience), so it probably represents the legal reality. But the user may get away with violating conditions if the automatic tests don't catch it, and there may be some leeway around the rules: it's definitely worth contacting the company to ask if the transaction went through ok.

Answer (score 0):

> The fine print read the exchange will be invalid if “**the event is less than 72 hours away**.”

The OP wrote the email on 16th at 23.30.  The concert is scheduled for 19th at 21.00.

Either way, whether the time limit is 72 hours or three days before the planned event, the request was submitted ***after*** **the deadline**.